# How to print file details of files matching grep pattern

Tags: bash, shell, loops, grep, xargs

I want to print file details along with grep output but unable to do so.  E.g., for the command

```
grep 3456 A.txt
```

I get the output

```
A.txt
```

but would like the output

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tarun tarun   41356911 Aug 25 01:31 A.txt
```

I tried the following without success:

1. `grep 34567 A.txt | xargs ls -tlr`
2. `grep 34567 A.txt | while read line ; do echo "$line" | date %s.%N ; done`
3. `grep -Hr 34567 A.txt | awk -F: '{"stat -c %z "$1 | getline r; print r": "$0 }'`
4. `grep 34567 A.txt | awk -F: '{"date -r \""$1"\" +\"%F %R\"" | getline d; print d,$0}'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grep -Zl 3456 * | xargs -0 ls -l
```

with GNU grep.  The options are:

- `grep -Z` and `xargs -0`: separate output names by a NULL byte instead of by whitespace.  This way you can handle filenames that include spaces.
- `grep -l`: print only the filenames that match
- `ls -l`: Standard `ls` long output, which appears to be what you are asking for.

Tested on latest cygwin.

Comment: It Worked.. thanks a lot . illustration you have provided was much needed.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't need for `xargs` here; `find` can be used to both run `grep` and run `ls`, or even to emit `ls`-style output itself.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
       -exec grep -q -e '1234567' -- '{}' ';' \
       -exec ls -l {} +
```

...or, even better:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
       -exec grep -q -e '1234567' -- '{}' ';' \
       -ls
```

The `-ls` action uses an output format akin to `ls -l`.